# Spring AMQP @RabbitListener custom retry on business error best practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

Following scenario: I have a `@RabbitListener` picking up messages from RabbitMQ. Sometimes the message runs into an error because I can not find the related business object. In this case I have no possibility to reply to the sender so I just want to ignore this message after certain amount of retry.

My solution: In my `@RabbitListener` whenever it is not possible to find the business object I throw a custom runtime exception. In my configuration I have a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` with max attempts and a custom recoverer.

What is the best practice for handling such cases? Can I configure diffrent recoverer class when having more than one `@RabbitListener`?

See my configuraion:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(new CustomMessageConverter());
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);

    Advice[] adviceChain = new Advice[] { interceptor() };
    factory.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .recoverer(new CustomRejectAndRecoverer())
            .build();
}
```

And this is my `CustomRejectAndRecoverer`:

```
public class CustomRejectAndRecoverer implements MessageRecoverer {

    @Override
    public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(cause) instanceof BusinessObjectNotFoundRuntimeException) {
            throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Retry Policy Exhausted",
                    new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(cause), message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently need a different container factory for each different retry configuration.

In [2.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#annotation-error-handling), we have added a new `errorHandler` attribute to the annotation so each listener can have a customized error handler, regardless of the container factory it was created by.

This was in the [first milestone release](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/30/spring-amqp-2-0-milestone-1-available); the current milestone is M2 and M3 will be out shortly. The GA release is expected in June.

Comment: Thx that looks like a great improvement. Did you also consider adding an attribute for concurrent consumers? When I want to have different listeners to have different number of consumers I am also forced to have more than one container factory.

Comment: You should open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and, of course, [contributions are always welcome](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Answer (score 0):

If common logic from the shared `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` doesn't fit your requirements for particular `@RabbitListener`, you have to declare a new one, with those custom options, e.g. a new `MessageRecoverer` on the matter.

For that purpose the `@RabbitListener` has attribute:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 * @return the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```